# Select fields of main table in query while having all the autofields of associated table in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

## What I want

Only 2 fields from a `UsersTable` and the `autoFields` of the associated Table called `PrimaryBankAccounts`

using Query Finder

**Version**: Cake 3.2.4

## Associations

Inside UsersTable.php

```
    $this->hasOne('PrimaryBankAccounts', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => ['PrimaryBankAccounts.primary' => true],
        'className' => 'HrBankDetails'
    ]);
```

## What I tried

```
    // get user and primary bank details
    $usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users');
    $userAndPrimaryBankAccount = $usersTable->find()
    ->select(['id', 'name'])
    ->where(['Users.id' => $user_id])
    ->contain(['PrimaryBankAccounts'])
    ->autoFields(true)
    ->first();
```

## Why I tried what I tried

Last paragraph of this section in http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#passing-conditions-to-contain

And I quote:

> Alternatively, if you have multiple associations, you can use
>   autoFields():
>
> ```
> // Select id & title from articles, but all fields off of Users, Comments
> // and Tags.
> $query->select(['id', 'title'])
>     ->contain(['Comments', 'Tags'])
>     ->autoFields(true)
>     ->contain(['Users' => function($q) {
>         return $q->autoFields(true);
>     }]);
> ```

## What I got

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Calvin Wa",
    "email": "calvin@wa.com",
    "created": "2015-04-20T09:10:09+0800",
    "modified": "2015-04-20T09:10:09+0800",
    "group_id": 2,
    "phone": null,
    "mobile": null,
    "address": null,
    "comments": null,
    "forgot_password_token": null,
    "primary_bank_account": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "UOB for Calvin",
        "user_id": 8,
        "bank_name": "UOB",
        "account_type": "",
        "account_number": "123",
        "currency": "USD",
        "primary": true,
        "created": null,
        "modified": null
    }
}
```

## What I expected

```
{
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Calvin Wa",
    "primary_bank_account": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "UOB for Calvin",
        "user_id": 8,
        "bank_name": "UOB",
        "account_type": "",
        "account_number": "123",
        "currency": "USD",
        "primary": true,
        "created": null,
        "modified": null
    }
}
```